# Installing Visual Studio 2015 via MDT/WDS

Tags: deployment, wds, visual-studio, mdt

I'm working with MDT/WDS to deploy workstation images based on the role within my organization. One of these images requires VS2015, and I'd like to deploy it silently through MDT/WDS. I keep running into install issues whereby that application fails.

My settings for teh app are below:

[image]

Any and all help to streamline would be great.

Comment: Fails? Are there messages?

Answer (score 1):

Try using vs_enterprise.exe /adminfile .\Admindeployment.xml /norestart
Hopefully that would work.